# Redis on Windows 10 IoT PI

Tags: redis, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Just a quick question? Is it possible to run redis-server on a Windows 10 IoT Core for Raspberry PI? If not is it  possible to have any other DB (SQL or/and NoSQL) system on it?

Comment: Redis isn't just a database. Besides, you need an executable compiled for ARM. You can't use executables compiled for Intel processors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to run a database system such as SQLite embedded within your app.